# Is there a way to have jenkins only automatically trigger a build for new PRs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins pipelines and the Bitbucket plugin

I can Suppress automatic SCM triggering but that suppresses everything

Is there a way to have Jenkins track all my branches, PRs, and tags in the multibranch pipeline but only automatically trigger a build for new PRs and not branches or tags? But still have it possible to manually trigger a build of any branch or tag.

I could have logic in the pipeline that exits if the build is not user initiated and is not a PR- but is there a config option to do that sort of thing for me?